# How to use intent in Asynctask class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Please share how to use intent in doinbackground() or onpostexecute() methods Asynctask class.When I tried to use these codes it shows error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(asynctask.this, home.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

private Class<Home> clazz;
        public asynctask(Class<Home> clazz){
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }
```

**Asynctask doInBackground() method:**

```
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(cxt, "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is `asynctask` your activity?

Comment: You must always use intent in onPostExecute() method.. and don't use toast in doInBackground(),Toast should may be it is giving error in your code and plz post your logcat ..

Comment: please tell clearly am new to android i didnt know about asynctask class function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

How to asynctask class :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MyCustomAsyncTask(this).execute();
 }
```

**MyCustomAsyncTask.java**

```
public class MyCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private Context context;

    public MyCustomAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // write show progress Dialog code here
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // write service code here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(context, "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, home.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is meant by **youractivitycontext** in `new MyCustomAsyncTask(YourActivityContext).execute();`

Comment: When i imlpemented your code i got this error `The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type asyncdata.sync`

Answer (score 5):

Move this **Intent** part in `onPostExecute(...)` method of `AsynckTask`

Comment: When i moved **Intent** to `onPostExecute(...)` means it shows this error **The constructor Intent(Async, Class<Home>) is undefined** @Manish

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground(Void... arg0)` should do only background task 
you should put other code in `onPostExecute(...)` method. so that when background  task is over move to other activity.

** Don't try to touch UI from `doInBackground(....)` your app may crash.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't interact with UI in `doInBackground(....)`. you can only interact with UI in `onPostExecute(...)`. Just like thread you cann't interact with UI in Thread for UI we use Handler.

Answer (score 0):

Always put intent in `onPostExecute`. This will ensure that your UI thread is in sync.

For example if your want to show that on receiving right credentials the user should move to next  activity or else should be shown a message "Invalid credentials" in case they're wrong. Your `onPostExecute` should look like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
     if(success){
         Intent intent = new Intent(<CurrentActivity>.this, <NextActivity>.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
     else{
         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```